# What does the register of MIPS store when loading a word?

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to load the word "AAAAAAAAH" in register $t2. When I do so, t2 has the value: 41414141. What does it mean? And also, is the instruction with addi correct or does it mean overflow?

```
.data
word:.asciiz "AAAAAAAAH"
.text
.globl main
main:
lw $t2,word
sll $t2,$t2,16
addi $t2,$t2,65535
jr $ra
```

Comment: You stored `AAAAAAAAH` as a string. You want `.int 0AAAAAAAAh` or similar instead.

Comment: Are you using "word" in the sense of an English-language word or a computer storage word?

Comment: `0x41` is `65`, which is the ASCII code of `'A'`.

Comment: @Jester: GAS syntax doesn't allow trailing-h for hex constants, only C-style `0x`.  I assume neither does MARS's.  The right syntax would be `.int 0xAAAAAAAA`, for a 32-bit word with each nibble having the bit-pattern `1010`

Comment: @juliana: The hardware MIPS instruction `addi` uses a sign-extended 16-bit immediate, so only -32768 .. +32767.  But MARS probably supports it as a pseudo-instruction, constructing `65535` in another register (`$at`, the assembler-temporary which is named for this kind of usage), and adding it.  Look at the disassembly and find out.  If it's efficient, it uses `ori $at, $zero, 65535` / `add $t2, $t2, $at`, because bitwise booleans zero-extend their 16-bit immediate, unlike addi/addiu.

Comment: @CarlNorum it's string for mips

Comment: @melpomene, so I understand t2 stores only 4 values of A? Why doesn't it store the whole word?

Comment: @iulianaiuliana It stores 32 bits because it's a 32-bit register.

Comment: @melpomene, oh I see, thank you!